# Looking to write this ruby code in one line

Tags: ruby

I want to display my hash in a string like this:

```
The results are a=100, b=200
```

When I loop through the hash like so:

```
a = [{:a => 100}, {:b => 200}]
a.each do |x|
  x.each do |k,v|
    puts "#{k}=#{v}"
  end
end
```

the output returns strings in multiple lines

```
a=100
b=200
```

How can I change it to one string?

Comment: 1. Have you tried? 2. Why?

Comment: I rephrased your question, be aware how you ask, your question came across a lot like: "here is my code, I tried nothing, please do my task for me..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working with this

```
puts a.map{|x|x.map{|k,v|"#{k}=#{v}"}}.join(',')
```

Not sure if its the best solution though.

Answer (score -2):

`{:a => 100, :b => 200}.each { |k,v| puts "#{k}=#{v}" }`

Comment: I'm looking to put it in a string, something like "Hello #{ output }", not sure how it would work

Comment: I rephrased his question to make it clearer, you can try again :) bet you can solve it